# Merge two mp3 file in android

Tags: android, mp3

I want merge multiple mp3 file in android but for example I just do this with two file :

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath() + 0);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath() + 1);
                SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(fileInputStream, fileInputStream1);

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(soundFile.getAbsolutePath());

                int temp;
                while ((temp = sequenceInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(temp);
                }

                fileInputStream.close();
                fileInputStream1.close();
                sequenceInputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();
```

I recorded two sound with "ttt.mp30" and "ttt.mp31" file. then I want to merge it to "ttt.mp3"

but when I use this code for merge, it just create the ttt.mp3 witch play ttt.mp30 but it doesn't play ttt.mp31 file

whats the problem ?

thanks

**EDIT :**

if I use :

```
SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(fileInputStream1, fileInputStream);
```

insted of :

```
SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(fileInputStream, fileInputStream1);
```

the ttt.mp3 just play ttt.mp31 file

**Edit :**

the record option :

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: Maybe this would help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787409/concatenate-two-audio-files-and-play-resulting-file

Comment: You can't merge two audio files as they were raw data.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein what should I do ?

Comment: Possibly, play the two files one after another? (eventually capturing the audio and save it as a new mp3).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein How can I record mp3 file with android ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein can you help me in this case ?

Comment: No, because I haven't done it before. Some research will lead you to interesting resulsts, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class TwoFiles
 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream("path\\1.mp3");  // first source file
    FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream("path\\2.mp3");//second source file
    SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);
    FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream("path\\final.mp3");//destinationfile

    int temp;

    while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1)
    {
        // System.out.print( (char) temp ); // to print at DOS prompt
        fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
    }
    fostream.close();
    sistream.close();
    fistream1.close();
    fistream2.close();
}
}
```