# Joining multiple audio files into a single audio file in client side

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, html5-audio

We are building a exercise app using ionic framework, which need to play multiple audio files in sequence with specific interval between each audio file. We got this working. Now we need to join the audio files into a single file.

Example: File_1 (4 mins in length), File_2 (3 mins in length). We need a new combined single audio file which should be of 10 mins length (File_1 + 3 mins silence + File_2)

Is there way to get this in a client side mobile application using angular or cordova?

Comment: If you are asking to "How to do that" so there is no specific answer. Although there are libraries for handling audio on PCM or buffer level.

Comment: what is the file format?

Comment: if you are building a mobile application ,you can use java to join your mp3 files.
To call java file you have to write a plugin in cordova which is going to call it. You can take the example of "Toast" plugin in cordova.

Comment: I know this isnt client side but if you are using a node server you could process the audio there http://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2013/5/31/using-nodejs-to-join-audio-files

Comment: What about ffmpeg.js in the browser?
https://paul.kinlan.me/running-ffmpeg-with-wasm-in-a-web-worker/

I totally get the idea of this question, if the conversion is done on the client side you save a lot of processing of the backend side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Client-side javascript cannot do that, but it's possible on server-side.

Basic technically steps:

- send those files to server
- server does whatever you want and sends result back

If you are using node.js it's pretty easy

- send files to server using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)
- modify files server-side using [node-stream](https://github.com/qawemlilo/node-streams) and send back

This [article](http://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2013/5/31/using-nodejs-to-join-audio-files) describes basic mp3 file concatenation on node.js

#### But if you still want client-side. Theoretically this should work.

Note, this is very hackish way, you might hit many restrictions (application speed, battery consumption, local storage limit, etc) and you still will not have single file, but single format.

- Convert files to **base64** using [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161897/converting-audio-file-to-base64-using-javascript)

And use custom format like

```
var CustomFile = function(array_of_base64_files){
    var prepared_files = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array_of_base64_files.length; i++) {
        var file = array_of_base64_files[i];
        prepared_files.push({
            created: Date.now(),
            order: i,
            base64: file
        });
    };
    this.export = function(){
        return prepared_files;
    }
};
```

- Save it to browser by using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html), it has some limits which you can read in docs
- When you want to play it, get back `CustomFile` from pouchdb
- decode those base64 to file and use `window.URL.createObjectURL(formBlob);` so that HTML5 Audio can play it

Comment: Just a note: PouchDB allows directly storing Blobs as attachments, so you don't need to convert to base64 (which is inefficient): http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html

Answer (score 3):

You could create a cordova plugin that manage the files concat in the javascript layer but really join them in the native layer.

Other interesting question about audio merging (only in Android):

- [Android concat 2 audio (wav or mp3) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112372/android-concat-2-audio-wav-or-mp3-files)
- [How to merge two mp3 files into one (combine/join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-join)
- [Concatenate two audio files and play resulting file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787409/concatenate-two-audio-files-and-play-resulting-file)